# Find all records that have X tags ordered by ascending time, BUT, the ones that match the most tags should be grouped first

Tags: sql, postgresql, tags

Ok, this is a little hard to explain, and the title is not the best :/ but, basically, I have 3 tables and I'm trying to write a query that returns them with 2 levels of ordering. The first by the amount of "tags" each row has, and the second by when that row was created.

```
Table1: Items
  * ID
  * Name
  * CreatedAt

Table2: Tags
  * ID
  * Name

Table3: TaggedItems
  * TagID
  * ItemID
```

And I would like to list all items that have 1 or more tags, in ascending order by when they when created. But, and here's where I'm having issues, I want the ordering to be based on the number of tags that match an item, and, within that ordering, apply the ascending criteria.

So, let's say I have:

```
Item1 -> CreatedAt(0), Tags(A, B)
Item2 -> CreatedAt(0), Tags(A)
Item3 -> CreatedAt(1), Tags(B)
Item4 -> CreatedAt(1), Tags(A, B)
```

Then searching for all items with tags A and B must return first `Item1` and `Item4` and order those by ascending `CreatedAt`. And then `Item2` and `Item3` and order those by `CreatedAt` ascending. So the result would be:

```
* Item1
* Item4
* Item2
* Item3
```

I am inexperienced with SQL so maybe there are very well known solutions to this if I'm even explaining it correctly?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT` join of `Items` to `TaggedItems` (just in case an item does not have any tags at all) and group by item.
Finally sort by the number of tags descending and then by the date:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM Items i LEFT JOIN TaggedItems t 
ON t.ItemID = i.ID
GROUP BY i.ID, i.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(t.TagID) DESC, i.CreatedAt
```

The table `Tags` is not needed.

But if you want the results for a list of tags like `'A'` and `'B'` then:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM Items i 
LEFT JOIN TaggedItems ti ON ti.ItemID = i.ID
LEFT JOIN Tags t ON t.ID = ti.TagID AND t.Name IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY i.ID, i.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(t.ID) DESC, i.CreatedAt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional sort:

```
select i.*, x.no_tags
from items
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) no_tags
    from taggedItems ti
    inner join tags t on t.id = ti.tagID
    where ti.ItemID = i.ID and t.name in ('A', 'B')
) x
order by
    (x.no_tags > 1) desc,
    case when x.no_tags > 1 then i.createdAt end desc,
    createdAt
```

The query starts from the `items` table, and then uses a `lateral join` to retrieve the count of matching tags that belong to the target list (I used `('A', 'B')` as in your example). Then, the `order by` puts items that have more than 1 tag first, and uses a conditional expression to sort them by descending date; records with just one tag are not taken into account by this sort criteria, and fall into the last sort criteria, that orders by ascending date.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    select i.id,i,name
    from Items i join TaggedItems ti on i.ID=ti.ItemID
    join Tags t on t.ID=ti.TagID
    group by i.id,i,name
    order by count(*),CreatedAt
```

The phrase `order by count(*)` works for most database servers.